# Secure tunnel from SSH server to target host

Tags: jsch, tunnel

My java application connects to an SSH server and runs a third party utility by ChannelExec of Jsch. Then, this application makes unsecured/uncompresed file transfer to another server on which an SSH server is installed.

The flow is:

JavaApplicationHost --> SSHServer1(3rd party utility runs) --> SSHServer2

I want file transfers between these SSH servers to be secured/compressed. But, I cannot use any platform dependent utilities such as ssh command. I cannot install anything on these SSH servers. I just can use JSch to these SSH servers.

Is there a way to secure/compress communication between these SSH servers by JSch or any other alternatives ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, you cannot use JSch (or anything else) make a secure connection between a server and another machine.

Answer (score -1):

There is a jump host example of Jsch at http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/JumpHosts.java.html that cascades multiple JSch sessions.

The flow can be:

JavaApplicationHost --(JSchSession1)--> SSHServer1(3rd party utility runs) --(JSchSession2)--> SSHServer2

If I can create another tunnel by JSchSession2 between these SSH servers, I will be able to secure/compress the 3rd party application.

I will test and update here.

Thanks!

Comment: But that won't create a secure connection for 3rd party utility on the Server 1. You would have to install a Java application that uses JSch on Server 1 to create a tunnel your the utility. What is against your requirements.

Comment: Hello Martin!

You are right. Jump Host example doesn't help. As I understand, it always creates local port forwarding in application side. So, I cannot create a JSch session between SSH servers.

If I connect to SSHServer1 by JSsch and run an ssh client command to open a tunnel to SSHServer2, it is OK. So, If can do that, can SSH servers do that internally on behalf of me ?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by *"can SSH servers do that internally on behalf of me"*. You can use JSch to execute `ssh` on Server 1 to create a tunnel to Server 2, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Martin, I mean, connecting to SSHServer1 and running a command line ssh utility to open tunnel to SSHServer2 are technically possible. Because of this possibility, is there a feature on SSHServers to invoke them to to this job automatically ? For example, I use JSch, and I want to invoke OpenSSH to create secure tunnel to another OpenSSH without running command line ssh command. Thanks!

Comment: No there's no such functionality.